# In InDesign, How to apply an Object Style to the frames those have same specific link image?

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-scripting, object-styles

Is it possible to force indesign search for frames by their links and apply a specified object style to them?
Any Script will appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean "by their links"? Do you want to apply an object style to all frames containing a linked graphic?

Comment: For example: I want to apply object style "fruits color", Only to frames those contain "apple.tif", and not to those contain any other link. Only to apple ones!

Comment: What about strawberries or potatoes? How it the script supposed to know what are fruits and what are not? See what I mean?

Comment: I'm not a programmer, I'm working on designs! so I dunno how it should know! Indesign in link panel has a column that contains "location of the link" (page column), So in my opinion it knows so much things! ;)

Comment: ...and links are addresses and text value as I know. not a physical matter that computer should know.

Comment: @Vinny I don’t see what you mean. What do strawberries or potatoes have to do with whether a frame contains a link to the file _apple.tif_ or _xysveodnwhfu.png_? It is certainly possible to loop through links in a document, filter by file name, and then apply a style to the containing frame of all instances of a given file.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know coding, but my logic tells me that changing the image to another folder makes it easy to search the frames with missing links and  apply the style. Then return the image to the source folder.

Comment: Yes yes @Janus, as I said it before too!! I meant that in a simple example of apple! now I see a logical simple example just complicated people!! A Specific object style to apply to frames those contains a specific linked file! Specifics are which I need to say to application.

Comment: I just found scripts to delete frames with missing links, instead deleting them, the point will be applying a style.

Comment: @Danielillo It would be great dan, post that script here please! it could be useful for developers!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet is it possible to scripting this?

Comment: @RoozbehE Yes, it is absolutely possible, and probably not very difficult. I don’t have access to my computer or InDesign while I’m on holiday, but it shouldn’t be too difficult. You may have better chances finding someone who will help you with the actual scripting if you ask on the Adobe forums—they get quite a few scripting questions and are usually glad to help.

Comment: `var myGraphicFrames = app.activeDocument.rectangles;  
for (i=myGraphicFrames.length-1; i>=0; i--) {  
    if (myGraphicFrames[i].graphics.length < 1)  
        myGraphicFrames[i].remove();  
}  `  this script delete empty  graphic frames

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Really appreciate for your assistance and taking my issue so serious. I'll post a request in Adobe forum but also looking forward for your script too... If you ever will have a time or mood for this. thank you again.

Comment: And this is the [link](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1470744) for the script to remove frames with missing links:

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I meant what about strawberries.tif or patatoes.tif files ^^ Yes, it's definitely possible to browse linked files names, I've done it in the past. But my question was "what is the script supposed to look for". If it's only "apple.tif", it's easy. If it's a .txt list of occurences, it's still possible but require more work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this... 
Works just like a grep query.

```
// [310718] Link2ObjectStyle
// Apply object style to graphic frames in regard to linked file name
// written by Vinny

if (parseFloat(app.version) < 6) {
    main();
} else {
    app.doScript(main, ScriptLanguage.JAVASCRIPT, undefined, UndoModes.ENTIRE_SCRIPT, "Link2ObjectStyle");
}

function main() {
    if (app.documents.length > 0) {

        //------------
        //Variables 
        var
            myDoc = app.documents[0],
            myObjectStyles = myDoc.objectStyles.everyItem(),
            myLinks = myDoc.allGraphics;

        //------------
        //Dialog box  
        var myDialog = app.dialogs.add({
            name: "Apply object style to graphic frames in regard to linked file name",
            canCancel: true
        });
        with(myDialog) {
            with(dialogColumns.add()) {
                with(borderPanels.add()) {
                    with(dialogColumns.add()) {
                        staticTexts.add({
                            staticLabel: "File name contains:"
                        });
                    }
                    with(dialogColumns.add()) {
                        var myTextEditField = textEditboxes.add({});
                    }
                }
                with(borderPanels.add()) {
                    with(dialogColumns.add()) {
                        staticTexts.add({
                            staticLabel: "Apply object style:"
                        });
                    }
                    with(dialogColumns.add()) {
                        var myObjectStylesMenu = dropdowns.add({
                            stringList: myObjectStyles.name,
                            selectedIndex: 0
                        });
                    }
                }
            }

            if (myDialog.show() == true) {
                var myString, myObjectStyle, myObjectStylesMenu, fileName, j = 0;
                myString = myTextEditField.editContents;
                myObjectStyle = myDoc.objectStyles[myObjectStylesMenu.selectedIndex];
                myDialog.destroy();

                //------------
                //let's rock
                if (myString == "") {
                    alert("you didn't enter any string");
                    return null;
                } else {

                    for (i = 0; myLinks.length > i; i++) {
                        if (myLinks[i].itemLink.name.search(myString) != -1) {
                            myLinks[i].parent.applyObjectStyle(myObjectStyle);
                            j++;
                        }
                    }

                //------------
                //end
                    if (j == 0) {
                        alert("String could not be found\nScript ends");
                    } else {
                        alert(j + " objects found.\nYou're done");
                    }
                }

            } else {
                myDialog.destroy()
            }
        }

    } else {
        alert("Open a document");
        return null
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Vinny, This is what I wanted, really appreciate your effort, apples and strawberries are now free to roam around my documents!!! :D

Comment: You're welcome. Have you tred it? Does it work fine for You?

Comment: A • M • A • Z • I • N • G • !

Comment: @Vinny I tried it in a test document like yours, but need to go to work and run it there, most matter in my mind was issues with multi-purpose objects and wanted to make sure script detects every kind of objects like, inline anchored, custom anchored, outside of the page, in multi pages, anchored in table, in groups (with and without anchor), and normal placed images. Script found everything. Before this with some other scripts I had some issues that not all kind of objects detected by script, and it was most annoying thing! But now this one is working so fine!

Answer (score 3):

Tested script to create an empty style to all frames with .eps or .tif. Running the script add two object styles to the document that can be modified.

[image: Styles]

```
//ApplyObjectStylesTo_ContainersOf_TIF_EPS.jsx  
//Uwe Laubender  

/** 
* @@@BUILDINFO@@@ ApplyObjectStylesTo_ContainersOf_TIF_EPS.jsx !Version! Thu     Dec 12 2013 13:15:30 GMT+0100 
*/  

//Edit your style names here. Change the name between the two " " only!!  
//OR: edit your object styles in InDesign after running the script.  

var styleNameForEPS = "EPS-Containers-Only";  
var styleNameForTIF = "TIF-Containers-Only";  

app.scriptPreferences.userInteractionLevel =     UserInteractionLevels.interactWithAll;  

app.doScript(_ApplyObjectStylesToContainers, ScriptLanguage.JAVASCRIPT, [],     UndoModes.ENTIRE_SCRIPT, "Apply object styles to containers for TIF and EPS graphics");  

function _ApplyObjectStylesToContainers(){  

var d=app.documents[0];  
var allGraphicsArray = d.allGraphics;  

if(!d.objectStyles.itemByName(styleNameForEPS).isValid){  
d.objectStyles.add({name:styleNameForEPS});  
};  

if(!d.objectStyles.itemByName(styleNameForTIF).isValid){  
d.objectStyles.add({name:styleNameForTIF});  
};  

for(var n=0;n<allGraphicsArray.length;n++){  

//The EPS case:  
if(allGraphicsArray[n].getElements()[0].constructor.name === "EPS"){  
    allGraphicsArray[n].parent.appliedObjectStyle =     d.objectStyles.itemByName(styleNameForEPS);  
    };  
//The TIF case  
if(allGraphicsArray[n].getElements()[0].constructor.name === "Image" && allGraphicsArray[n].getElements()[0].imageTypeName === "TIFF"){  
    allGraphicsArray[n].parent.appliedObjectStyle = d.objectStyles.itemByName(styleNameForTIF);  
    };  

};  

}; //END: function _ApplyObjectStylesToContainers()
```

Source: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1356643

Comment: Daniel, come back here. Vinny wrote an amazing script and it so handy and catchy. come here asap and get it! also don't forget to visit my question at adobe forum, vinny also added a mini gif video to explain the script: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2518997

Answer (score 0):

Ass I wrote in the comments:

> Unfortunately I don't know coding, but my logic tells me that changing the image to another folder makes it easy to search the frames with missing links and apply the style. Then return the image to the source folder.

This is the script to add a style to all the frames with missing links in a document:

```
var link, image, frame,  
doc = app.activeDocument,  
links = doc.links,  
counter = 0; 
nameOfObjectStyle = "YourStyle"; /**Replace *YourStyle* for the name of your style**/  
var objectStyleThatShouldBeApplied = app.documents[0].objectStyles.itemByName(     nameOfObjectStyle );

for (var i = links.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {  
if (links[i].status == LinkStatus.LINK_MISSING) {  
    try {  
        link = links[i];  
        image = link.parent;  
        frame = image.parent;  
      frame.applyObjectStyle( objectStyleThatShouldBeApplied , false, false );
        counter++;  
    }  
    catch (err) {  
        $.writeln(i + " - " + err);  
    }  
}  
}
```

Comment: Thank you dan... the object linkstatus maybe a clue for someone. maybe it could be a another parameter like "location" , "path" or name.