# Updating link to changed Word document results in wrong paragraph style in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, paragraph-styles, script, microsoft-word

I have over three hundred word documents linked into my InDesign CS6 project. The authors of these can update them with revised texts. The documents are all in *Normal* Word style, and I have a mapping to the InDesign Paragraph style *SpeciesText*.

This works well when setting up the link, but when updating the link, after the doc is changed, the mapping doesn’t apply. I have tried a VBA macro that creates a *SpeciesText* Style in the Word document and applies that to all text in the document so no mapping is needed. However, the *Update Link* processing makes a real mess of the text with incorrect italics and bold appearing.

I think what I need is an InDesign script that will loop through all of the links and look for linked files that have a filename ending in `Species.docx` and apply the *SpeciesText* Paragraph Style. (The document names are all of the form `nn.nnn Species.docx` where the `nn.nnnn` is of format `#0.000#`. Values are decimal numbers e.g. 12.034 or 3.2345.)

There are also some linked TXT documents with standard naming that I may also need to do something similar with, but I hope that I can adapt any suggestions to the main problem to apply to the TXT files too.

I can see that [this post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/113257/in-indesign-how-to-apply-an-object-style-to-the-frames-those-have-same-specific) has some of the elements that might help, but not sure how to focus on text frame links rather than *AllGraphics* and to apply *Paragraph* rather than *Objects* styles.